# Google Font text becoming unreadable in Firefox, font-weight 300

Tags: html, firefox

So yeah, I'm working on coding a website, and I'm primarily using the font "Robot Condensed" ( http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Roboto+Condensed )

Now the problem is I have a jQuery thing, where you hit the button and it expands to the full text. When you hit this though, the all of the font-weight: 300 texts on the page mess up, with no apparent way to return them to normal except by refreshing the page.

I don't believe the problem lies in the Javascript though, because I don't know of what in it could cause this, and also, it was doing this yesterday as well, before I implemented any Javascript (you would just scroll down the page and after a few seconds the font would mess up). I've only seen this issue in Firefox.

Normal
http://prntscr.com/t009m

Broken
http://prntscr.com/t005u

Normal
http://prntscr.com/t00fl

Broken
http://prntscr.com/t007z

It's like the font is becoming more thin or something. Has anyone ever experienced anything like this or might have any idea what's causing it?

Thanks.

EDIT: Okay, it seems to happen when I use any kind of jQuery on the page.

Comment: Are you on Windows with Clear Type turned on (a Windows type setting)? Note, if your browser doesn't have that font with that weight, the browser will *interpret* the font as that weight. Meaning, make it up. Beware.

Comment: Yeah, Windows with Clear Type turned on. Like I said, the font works normally for a time, but then it seems to go whack. I'm using  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: It looks just like a clear type problem to me. Have you tried toggling it off and checking? Without a link to see it myself, not sure what to tell you. And it's possible if you use jQuery for animation on that element or a parent, the method jQuery uses triggers the problem, possibly after a time (again, without seeing it...).